# Using Stream in Java

Tags: stream

I have a use case where I have a class "cls" which contains a timestamp field.
Now I have two stream A and B both containing objects of class cls.

I need to concat Stream B to Stream A but, if in stream A I find an object with same timestamp as object in Stream B, I need to replace the object is Stream A  with Object in Stream B.
Basically keeping the latest copy of duplicate timestamp.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have somehow used the below logic, but unable to figure out how to delete an element from Stream A if it matches to an element in B:

`Iterator<Measurement> itA =A.iterator();
while (A.hasNext())
{
Iterator<Measurement> itB = B.iterator();
while (itA.hasNext())
{
if (itA.next().getTimestamp().equals(itB.next().getTimestamp()))
{
    //deleting from A logic
}
}
}`

Comment: Are you talking about Java 8’s `Stream` API or what kind “stream”?

Comment: Yes, Java 8's stream API. Cant loop through the stream more than once, so I guess, using stream for this use case is not the right idea.

Comment: Any suggestions anyone?